# Apache Tomcat and Mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, railo, mod-jk

We have been running Apache with Tomcat using mod_jk for about a month now with out issues. This morning I have started seeing the error below in the mod_jk log files.

I am fairly new to using mod_jk and am not sure how to increase the number of connections, see the number of active connections and/or kill of connections that are idle or dead.

Any ideas/help would be much appreciated.

```
[Thu Sep 19 11:02:42 2013] [1644:11984] [warn] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3177): Unable to get the free endpoint for worker Worker1 from 10 slots
[Thu Sep 19 11:02:42 2013] [1644:11984] [error] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2726): Could not get endpoint for worker=Worker1
[Thu Sep 19 11:02:42 2013] [1644:11984] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2788): Service error=0 for worker=Worker1
```

Comment: Do you have jkstatus defined as a worker and accessible via Apache? If so, I suggest pulling it up and seeing if you want to change anything. if you want to make any of it permanent, it'll have to go in the workers.properties file.
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added jkstatus and am able to see statistics. Tomcat seems to seize now about every hour and a half. I will post up errors that I see when it happens again.  Is there anything else I can look at for additional debugging?

Comment: With JK Status running I see some errors (Both Failed requests and Client Errors). The thing I notice is that the Number of Current Backend Connections always increases. In 28 minutes  it reached 8400. Is this normal or is this indicative of a configuration problem.

Comment: I guess normal would depend on usage. Our sites are all internal corporate sites with a few users, so we never go beyond a few hundred (I do know that this number is significantly more than the number of users at any point in time... probably multiple connections for each). Note sure what you can try tweaking, but workers.properties allows all sorts of connection-related config:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html

Comment: So it turns out this issue was a by product of another configuration issue. We had different Railo contexts configure to point to the same set of shared directories, some of the context's mapped to directories that were within the root context which caused Java thread locks.     Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this issue was a by product of another configuration issue. We had different Railo contexts configure to point to the same set of shared directories, some of the context's mapped to directories that were within the root context which caused Java thread locks